# Discard integer and keep floating point

Tags: bc, floating-point

I'm trying to remove an integer from a decimal value that I currently have.

current syntax:

```
h=$(echo "scale=2; (($e/$g/$g))" | bc) 
echo $h
```

The following is used to convert seconds to minutes and then hours however it returns "21.15" hours.

I want to keep the 0.15 and multiply it by 60 (leaving me with 9 minutes) -- and eventually 21 hours 9 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bc` remainder operator is `%`

> ```
>    expr % expr
>           The  result  of the expression is the "remainder" and it is com‐
>           puted in the following way.  To compute a%b, first a/b  is  com‐
>           puted to scale digits.  That result is used to compute a-(a/b)*b
>           to the scale of the maximum of scale+scale(b) and scale(a).   If
>           scale  is  set  to  zero  and both expressions are integers this
>           expression is the integer remainder function.
> ```

Ex.

```
$ echo '21.15 % 1' | bc
.15

$ echo '(21.15 % 1) * 60' | bc
9.00
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `bc` doc:

> expr / expr
>
> The  result  of  the expression is the quotient of the two expressions.  The scale of the result is the value of the variable scale.

So use `scale=0` to have an integer division:

```
>bc <<<'scale=2; 8/3'                                                                 
2.66                                                                                             

>bc <<<'scale=0; 8/3'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dc:

```
echo '21.15 1%60*p' | dc -f -
```

9.00